# How to generate and publish Code Coverage in gradle kotlin using Azure DevOps?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, azure-devops, jacoco

I am trying to integrate code coverage in gradle Kotlin as suggested in https://techblog.tbauctions.com/kotlin-azure-and-code-coverage/ but it's not working, below are the project files.

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    jacoco
}

val test by tasks.getting(Test::class) {
    useJUnitPlatform { }
}

tasks.withType(JacocoReport::class.java).all {
    reports {
        xml.isEnabled = true
        xml.destination = File("$buildDir/reports/jacoco/report.xml")
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    jacoco {
        toolVersion = "0.8.3"
        reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco")
    }
    finalizedBy("jacocoTestReport")
}
```

**Error - Task with name 'test' not found in project ':app'**

Also tried https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

> How to generate and publish Code Coverage in gradle kotlin using Azure DevOps?

According to the error message:

> Error - Task with name 'test' not found in project ':app'

It seems the task called `test` is not provided in the project. When using a JVM language plugin like [Java](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) in Gradle, a task called test is automatically provided. This task runs all tests under `src/test` by default.

The Java plugin adds a number of tasks to your project, including the `test` task:

[The Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html):

[image]

So, make sure you have add plugin Java in Gradle.

You could check [this document](https://medium.com/@arunvelsriram/jacoco-configuration-using-gradles-kotlin-dsl-67a8870b1c68) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey @Leo thanks however `gradlew clean test` is working without any java plugin.

Comment: Hey @Leo also I tried the document you have mentioned above still it's showing `unresolved reference tasks.jacocoTestReport`